# Placement of PGFPlots.net Bar graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, standalone

I'm trying to display these 2 graphs so that one is on top of another but every time I got them side by side
[image]
How can I display them so that one is on top of other so it look like this
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=15pt,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool1, tool2, tool3, tool4, 
        tool5, tool6, tool7},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,2) (tool4,3) (tool5,0) (tool6,2) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,0) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,3) (tool5,1) (tool6,1) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,6) (tool2,6)
  (tool3,8) (tool4,2) (tool5,6) (tool6,5) (tool7,6)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,2) (tool5,3) (tool6,2) (tool7,4)};
\legend{\strut never, \strut rarely, \strut sometimes, \strut often}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=15pt,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool1, tool2, tool3, tool4, 
        tool5, tool6, tool7},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,2) (tool4,3) (tool5,0) (tool6,2) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,0) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,3) (tool5,1) (tool6,1) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,6) (tool2,6)
  (tool3,8) (tool4,2) (tool5,6) (tool6,5) (tool7,6)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,2) (tool5,3) (tool6,2) (tool7,4)};
\legend{\strut never, \strut rarely, \strut sometimes, \strut often}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Tried to do something with `\begin{groupplot}` and `\begin{figure}[h!]` but it doesn't seem to work. No need to mention that I'm not an expert in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `groupplots`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
       group size=1 by 2,
       vertical sep=1.8cm
       },
    ybar stacked,
    /pgf/bar width=15pt,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool1, tool2, tool3, tool4, 
        tool5, tool6, tool7},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east, inner sep=2pt},
    ]
    
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,2) (tool4,3) (tool5,0) (tool6,2) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,0) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,3) (tool5,1) (tool6,1) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,6) (tool2,6)
  (tool3,8) (tool4,2) (tool5,6) (tool6,5) (tool7,6)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,2) (tool5,3) (tool6,2) (tool7,4)};
\legend{\strut never, \strut rarely, \strut sometimes, \strut often}

\nextgroupplot
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,2) (tool4,3) (tool5,0) (tool6,2) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,0) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,3) (tool5,1) (tool6,1) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,6) (tool2,6)
  (tool3,8) (tool4,2) (tool5,6) (tool6,5) (tool7,6)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,2) (tool5,3) (tool6,2) (tool7,4)};
\legend{\strut never, \strut rarely, \strut sometimes, \strut often}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit after comments

Sounds like you might be better off not using the `standalone` class, but a standard `article`. See an example below. Title and section headings are of course optional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\title{Lots of results!}
\author{Some Dude}
\date{} % remove to get todays date
\begin{document}

\maketitle % prints the info from \title, \author, \date

\section{Some numbers}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
       group size=1 by 2,
       vertical sep=1.8cm
       },
    ybar stacked,
    /pgf/bar width=15pt,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool1, tool2, tool3, tool4, 
        tool5, tool6, tool7},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east, inner sep=2pt},
    ]
    
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,2) (tool4,3) (tool5,0) (tool6,2) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,0) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,3) (tool5,1) (tool6,1) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,6) (tool2,6)
  (tool3,8) (tool4,2) (tool5,6) (tool6,5) (tool7,6)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,2) (tool5,3) (tool6,2) (tool7,4)};
\legend{\strut never, \strut rarely, \strut sometimes, \strut often}

\nextgroupplot
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,2) (tool4,3) (tool5,0) (tool6,2) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) (tool2,0) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,3) (tool5,1) (tool6,1) (tool7,0)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,6) (tool2,6)
  (tool3,8) (tool4,2) (tool5,6) (tool6,5) (tool7,6)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) (tool2,2) 
  (tool3,0) (tool4,2) (tool5,3) (tool6,2) (tool7,4)};
\legend{\strut never, \strut rarely, \strut sometimes, \strut often}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

As we can see here \dots

\section{Some other numbers}

\begin{center}
Add another diagram here
\end{center}
Etc. uzw. osb. and so on.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much. Do u know how to add some text after `\end{tikzpicture}`? I want to be able post graph, put some text. Put in another graph and put some text again

Comment: @etrusks If you're adding text in addition to the diagrams, you probably shouldn't be using the `standalone` class, but `article`. With `article` your original code would have worked, and adding text is just writing it in after `\end{tikzpicture}`. But what is your end goal, what kind of document are you creating?

Comment: Thanks a lot bro u are saving me! I'm kind of generating some data with C++ and want to display averages and all kinds of things from that data and I want to beautifully display it in graphs like this. But I also want to put some explanatory text under some graphs so it's not only visuals

Comment: @etrusks I added a very simple example with `article` to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot man you have helped me so much :) I just want to ask 1 more thing. If I want to enlarge graphs width using `\pgfplotsset{width=16cm,compat=1.8}` it kind of slipts to the right side. How could I slide it back so it's in the middle of the page

Comment: @etrusks Yes, if things are wider than the text block the poke out in the right margin. One option is to add `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and use `\begin{adjustbox}{center} <tikzpicture code here> \end{adjustbox}`.

Comment: Bro this is sick, you have given everything I need. Works just perfect! :) Can't say thank you enough man! U just made my day. Glad there are people like u in the world :) Thanks bro! This will be the best looking document ever now :D